# Unable to add fontawesome icons in highcharts formatter functions

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to add fontawesome icons in Highcharts sankey charts for nodes and links using formatters which is not working as expected.

Below is what I have tried.
I added nodeFormatter and formatter which returns a markup ( used a React component and returned a markup out of it). Adding an fontawesome icon isn't showing up here.

[Sankey Highcharts](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-ipn787)

If someone did something similar, can you please let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One options to set is `dataLabels.useHTML` to true when you want to use font awsome in formatter.

```
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      useHTML: true,
      nodeFormatter: function () {
        const ll = renderToStaticMarkup(
          <CustomLabel name={this.point.name} weight={10} />
        );
        console.log("element rendered ", ll);
        return ll;
      },
      formatter: function () {
        const ll = renderToStaticMarkup(
          <CustomLabel name={this.point.weight} weight={50} />
        );
        console.log("element rendered ", ll);
        return ll;
      }
    },
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-6807sy

Comment: How stupid I am. I knew this property but missed it somehow